# How to consume HTTPS based webservice (exposed by java server) from C#.NET Windows application

Tags: c#

I Would like to call methods from HTTPS based webservice exposed by javaserver using C#.NET Windows application as a client.
My Java server has some certificates in `.cer` and `.jks` file formats.

My question is :
do I need to create some certificates in my local machine or
do I need to access the certificates stored in java server in order to provide the communication between my .NET client and Java server?

Comment: Are client certificates required to access the web services? If so you will probably need to issue them from your server to the user/machine who will be accessing them.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your Response. i have created certificates necessary for accessing the services , but still i m facing the following error: "An error occured while making HTTP request to https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  this could be due to the fact that server certificates is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case this could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding   between client and server" could you please help me to Resolve the Issue. Thanks in Advance.